# Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: account. Django

Tags: django

I know there are Duplicates of this question, but they didn't solve the issue.

my django app is conflicting between `django-user-acccounts; account` and `allauth.account`

M Installed App

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',

    'django.contrib.sites',
    # 'allauth',
    'allauth.account', # django-allauth    # conflict
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'crispy_forms',

    'account',  # django-user-accounts     #conflict
    'pinax.referrals',  

    'kingEstateCore',
    'widget_tweaks',
]
```

I've tried renaming the `account` package inside my site_packages but no success.
I've also tried adding `AppConfig` but there was no `apps.py` module insite my site_packages/account.
Any Ideas pls

**Error TraceBack**

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\KingAfam\KingENV\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\KingAfam\KingENV\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\KingAfam\KingENV\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\KingAfam\KingENV\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\KingAfam\KingENV\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\KingAfam\KingENV\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\KingAfam\KingENV\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 95, in populate
"duplicates: %s" % app_config.label)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: account
```

Comment: what is the error you're getting and the full traceback might help.

Comment: I've updated my question with the Full Traceback

Comment: Is the package in `site_packages` allauth or your personal one

Comment: both `allauth` and  `account` are in the site_packages

Comment: @Mario looks like you're going to have to get rid of one of them

Comment: I've thought of if it but am trying to implement a referral system using pinax-referrals so I used the `allauth` for authentication and I want to use the`account` for the referral system

Comment: What I will suggest you do is to go and see how both models operate and make one custom, universal model of your own. You obviously need to sacrifice the views and everything (otherwise you might need to dig into site_packages and see what's inside), but other than that I don't think there's any way to do that.